# Why do I have to compile to get intellisense for the HTML helper object in asp.net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

When I add a new view I don't get intellisense for the HTML helper object until I compile. I guess it must be a VS issue. But what changes when I compile? What makes it work?

EDIT: More Details

I am running RC1 on VS2008 pro. I have had this issue since I started with MVC using preview 2.
When I create a new view I do not get intellisense for the HTML helper object until I compile again. I have seen this issue mentioned in other places and the main point of the question is what compiling does that make the intellisense work.

Edit: Update Details

I just updated to RC2 and am still having this issue. I have it on all the machines in my office. They all run VS2008 sp1 pro on Vista 32 or 64 bit business

Comment: Which version of the ASP.NET MVC framework are you using? I am unable to reproduce your issue with RC2.

Comment: I have RC1 but I have had the issue since Preview 2.

Comment: As far as I can tell, something must be wrong with either your install of VS2008, or an add-in that affects intellisense in some way. I have never heard of anyone having this problem.

Comment: Are you using views with code behind or not?

Comment: I sent out an email today, to the 20 or so developers on my team that are currently using the MVC framework - none of them reported having the same problem as you are having.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't really bother me I was just curious as the what makes it work after I compile

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be intended behavior.  One [ASP.NET MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-21-cs.aspx) has this to say:

> You should build your project (select
>   the menu option Build, Build Solution)
>   before opening the Add View dialog or
>   no classes will appear in the View
>   data class dropdown list.

The tutorial does not explain why this is the case, it just mentions that it is.  It's possible that the intellisense is actually looking at the compiled object, rather than the source code.

Comment: That is unrelated to his problem; his question is related to intellisense, and T4 templating, which is what your answer is related to, has nothing to do with intellisense.

Comment: This was not my question but is the same idea. For some reason Intellisense only works in MVC after you compile.